# Dagger2 to hilt migration: how to migrate application component with custom component.factory?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am trying to follow the migration guide to migrate a legacy application from dagger2 to hilt. Its application component is in the following structure:

```
abstract class ApplicationComponent : ApplicationDependencies {

    abstract fun inject(application: MyApp)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun applicationComponent(
            @BindsInstance myApp: MyApp,
            @BindsInstance sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
            @BindsInstance activeActivityProvider: ActiveActivityProvider,
            @BindsInstance appLifecycleObservable: Observable<ApplicationStateEvent>,
            @BindsInstance @EnvironmentName
            environmentName: String,
            schedulersComponent: SchedulerComponent,
            commonComponent: CommonComponent,
        ): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

and MyApp is like the following

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private ApplicationComponent component;
    // ... some code that defines appLifecyleObserver and other stuff

    public void onCreate() {
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(appLifecycleObserver);
        super.onCreate();
        
        // .. some code that initiates mSharedPreferences, environmentName etc.

        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.factory().applicationComponent(
                this,
                mSharedPreferences,
                activeActivityProvider,
                appLifecycleRelay,
                environmentName,
                DaggerSchedulersComponent.create(),
                DaggerCommonComponent.factory().commonComponent(this),
        );
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

the example in https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide.html#accessing-the-interfaces convert ApplicationComponent to EntryPoint, but in that way I cannot bind those extra stuff in my factory. What is the proper way to deal with this Component.Factory?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after working on it for a few days: I eventually refactored this part to separate them out of the ApplicationComponent. I then inject them to the application and init them onCreate, or simply provide them with application context